# iTextsharp pdf cannot open when hosting in IIS

Tags: itext

I am using iTextSharp for creating PDF for reports in ASP.Net (c#). 
Pdf is created successfully & can be opened when running the Application, but when iam hosted in IIS it cannot open in PDF and gives error :

"adobe reader could not open pdf because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged "

My code like:

```
Document pdfDoc = new Document();
pdfDoc.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4.Rotate());

string filepath = "Demo" + ".pdf";

string attachment = "attachment; filename=" + filepath;
Response.Charset = String.Empty;
Response.ClearContent();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
Response.ContentType = "application/PDF";

PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);

pdfDoc.Open();

//Adding some paragraph in to the pdfdoc.            

pdfDoc.Close();

Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Response.End();
```

I am waiting for your greatfull ideas

Comment: What is that "Response.Write(pdfDoc);" line good for? The PDF itself is exported by means of "PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);". Thus, that Response.Write call will most likely add trash to the response.

Comment: is there any better way to do this ?

Comment: why do you want to do this (i.e. return something in addition to the PDF) anyways? And if you don't want to, simply remove that "Response.Write(pdfDoc);" line.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this an old post, but I had a problem with itextsharp, and in my case was about the folder permissions to the iis user.

I just right clicked on my main folder, went to the security tab and chose the .Net User(were 2 for me) and gave full control. And that was my problem, and solved. Hope this can help someone else.